# Finding content between multiple start and end tags using regular expression

Tags: ruby, regex

I'm trying to run a regular expression (Ruby) on a file containing code and custom comment tags. I want to find all text between (`/*+ ... +*/`), single line or multiline.

Given:

```
/*+
   # Testing Documentation #
   ## Another Documentation Line ##
   This is also picked up
+*/
Some code here that is ignored
/*+ # More documentation # +*/
```

I would want to match each group of text between the open and closing of `/*+ ... +*/`

I've tried the following reg ex which works great for the single line example. But if I enable the multiline option, it picks up everything between the first match and last match instead of matching two or more groups.

```
/(?<=\/\*\+)(.*)(?=\+\*\/)/
```

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make the match in the middle non-greedy (`(.*?)`). Here's a permalink to Rubular:

http://rubular.com/r/0SuNNJ3vy6

The expression I used was `/(\/\*\+)(.*?)(\+\*\/)/m`, fine-tune as you see fit.

```
text.scan(/(\/\*\+)(.*?)(\+\*\/)/m).map(&:join)
#=> ["/*+\n   # Testing Documentation #\n   ## Another Documentation Line ##\n   This is also picked up\n+*/", "/*+ # More documentation # +*/"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe that'll help you. This works in JS:

```
/(?:\/\*\+)([\w\W]*?)(?=\+\*\/)/igm
```